# Google Sheets formula update issue

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, format, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet with the following information in it.

Master_Sheet

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Yellow | M |
| 2 | 2 | Purple | F |
| 3 | 3 | Green | F |
| 4 | 4 | Red | F |

I have it set up so that the cells in Sheet 2 are in the following format

- Sheet2!B1 = Master_Sheet!A1
- Sheet2!B2 = Master_Sheet!C1
- Sheet2!B3 = Master_Sheet!D1
- Sheet2!B6 = Master_Sheet!A2
- Sheet2!B7 = Master_Sheet!C2
- Sheet2!B8 = Master_Sheet!D2

Can be seen below

Sheet2

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | 1 |
| 2 | Sex | M |
| 3 | Trait | Yellow |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 | ID | 2 |
| 7 | Sex | F |
| 8 | Trait | Purple |
| 9 |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 | ID |  |
| 12 | Sex |  |
| 13 | Trait |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 15 | ID |  |
| 16 | Sex |  |
| 15 | Trait |  |
| 16 |  |  |
| 16 |  |  |

Is there a simple way to have this pattern repeat so that Sheet2 B11:13 will = Master_Sheet! A3,C3,D3? I need to it to repeat several thousand times. I tried the following but the row numbers would not update as a pasted/filled after my initial manual input

- B1=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,2,1)
- B2=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,2,4)
- B3=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,2,3)
- B6=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,3,1)
- B7=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,3,4)
- B8=INDEX(Master_Inventory!$A:$C,3,3)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,wraprows(,2,),
     Δ,reduce(wraprows("skip_",2,),sequence(counta(Master_Sheet!A:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;{{"ID";"Sex";"Trait"},tocol(index(choosecols(Master_Sheet!A:D,1,3,4),c))};Σ;Σ})),
       filter(Δ,index(Δ,,1)<>"skip_"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to do this in Excel this formula works in my sheet:

=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:C4)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK({"ID","Sex","Trait"},TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(A1:C4,y),1,3,2))),{""."".""},{""."".""}))),1),"")

The data is in range A1:C4 as shown in the original question.